# Cannot send VK_SHIFT using P/INVOKE from C#

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, interop

We are trying to handle a file download dialog in C# (from IE).

What we'd like to do is clear out the text box in the dialog, by sending messages to the window (Home, CTRL-A, Backspace).

I've pasted some of the code here not all, but it seems that the CTRL key is not fired (i don't see the actual text being highlighted):

```
// HOME DOWN
NativeMethods.SendMessage(new HandleRef(null, _hwnd), NativeMethods.WM_KEYDOWN, new IntPtr(0x24), IntPtr.Zero);
Thread.Sleep(1000);

// HOME UP
NativeMethods.SendMessage(new HandleRef(null, _hwnd), NativeMethods.WM_KEYUP, new IntPtr(0x24), IntPtr.Zero);
Thread.Sleep(1000);

// CTRL DOWN
NativeMethods.SendMessage(new HandleRef(null, _hwnd), NativeMethods.WM_KEYDOWN, new IntPtr(0x11), IntPtr.Zero);
Thread.Sleep(1000);

// END DOWN
NativeMethods.SendMessage(new HandleRef(null, _hwnd), NativeMethods.WM_KEYDOWN, new IntPtr(0x41), IntPtr.Zero);
Thread.Sleep(1000);

// END UP
NativeMethods.SendMessage(new HandleRef(null, _hwnd), NativeMethods.WM_KEYUP, new IntPtr(0x41), IntPtr.Zero);
Thread.Sleep(1000);

// CTRL UP
NativeMethods.SendMessage(new HandleRef(null, _hwnd), NativeMethods.WM_KEYUP, new IntPtr(0x11), IntPtr.Zero);
 Thread.Sleep(5);
```

Is there anything that i'm missing when using the SendMessage function combined with WM_KEYUP and WM_KEYDOWN messages?

The SendMessage function is declared like this:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern IntPtr SendMessage(HandleRef hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
```

Comment: Don't use `SendMessage()` to simulate input. Either use `SendInput()` or `SendMessage()` with appropriate messages to actually clear the text (`WM_SETTEXT`).

Comment: We've tried using WM_SETTEXT but in conjunction with the IE download dialog, it seems that setting the text did not actually affect the dialog (it saves the file into a different location than the one that the edit box was set to). using key sending it worked fine.

Comment: There are lots of things you are doing wrong with the posted code, keystrokes are posted, not sent, you can't control the modifier key state of another process with PostMessage.  But scratch this, the IE download confirmation dialog is special.  A high-profile attack target, it can't be messed with.

Comment: Why would you be downloading from the internet by poking key messages at IE? It's trivial to do it programmatically without invoking the beast.

Comment: I agree with @HansPassant - you should probably NOT be doing this.

Comment: @Hans Passant "it can't be messed with". So I was told regarding the Outlook warning dialog that comes up when you connect to Outlook as a COM Server, too... ;-)

Comment: We are automating a license generator app web app). The license is then downloaded, and so we need a way to automate that dialog...

Answer (score 0):

Try the [keybd_event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646304%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API function instead.

Comment: "This function has been superseded. Use SendInput instead."

Comment: @lysergic-acid It's much easier to call `keybd_event` than `SendInput`.